# Jquery UI - margin issue with jquery resizable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, margin, jquery-ui-resizable

Please check my code below. I am using JQuery UI for Resizable. I have margin on an image and then I am applying JQuery resizable on image click and i am removing it when I click outside the image. Everything is working fine but except this behavior is removing the margin from image. Is there any way to keep the margin?

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-DQ69szlhi38/UCJwZqNfcJI/AAAAAAAAAcY/6gsenl0Mwr8/s72-c/google.jpg" style="margin:20px;"/>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('img').click(function(){
        $(this).resizable();
    });
});
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $('img');
    if ((!container.is(e.target)
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0)) {
        if ($('img').hasClass('ui-resizable')) {
            $('img').resizable('destroy');  
        }
    }
});
```

Please check the code in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wgdvza8j/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue. I am now pulling the margin from ui-wrapper and then applying on the image. Please check my code on js fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/wgdvza8j/6/

**HTML**

**JQuery**

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    var imgMarginTop,imgMarginRight,imgMarginBottom,imgMarginLeft;
    $('img').click(function(){
        $(this).resizable();
    });
});
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $('img');
    if ((!container.is(e.target)
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0)) {
        if ($('img').hasClass('ui-resizable')) {
            imgMarginTop = $('.ui-wrapper').css('marginTop');
            imgMarginRight = $('.ui-wrapper').css('marginRight');
            imgMarginBottom = $('.ui-wrapper').css('marginBottom');
            imgMarginLeft = $('.ui-wrapper').css('marginLeft');
            $('img').css({'marginTop':imgMarginTop,'marginRight':imgMarginRight,'marginBottom':imgMarginBottom,'marginLeft':imgMarginLeft});
            $('img').resizable('destroy');  
        }    
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI resizible sets inline CSS styles for your image including `margin: 0`. It means that in order to overload this margin you have to set CSS rules like this (`!important` is the way to make rule more specific then inline styles):

```
img {
    margin: 20px !important;
}
```

However I'm not sure why would you need this margin at all.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wgdvza8j/4/

Comment: Thanks for your help. But i need margin as i am adding margin dynamically. So I have programmed a functionality where users can add margin dynamically around the image but once user resize the image then it just deletes the margin from image. So !important won't work in my case as the margin is dynamic

Comment: I see. Then you can use [stop event](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#event-stop) to reapply margin once resizing is done.

Comment: It is not about resizing. If i dont do resizing and clicking on image then I am enabling resize but if i don't do resize and click outside then it is destroying the resizing and removing the margin. So if I add stop event then it wont kick in because i am not actually resizing the image. Can you please update this suggestion on this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wgdvza8j/4/. I will really appreciate that